# How to get a credential-provider that runs from another AWS IAM User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-js, aws-sts

The AWS account I work in has 2 main IAM users:

- User A has most of the important execution permissions (Lambda, SecretsManager, API GateWay...)
- User B has only 1 permission: AssumeRole to `targetRole`, a IAM Role in a 3rd party AWS account (on which I have no control / influence). `targetRole` is then used to perform SQS operations in the 3rd party AWS account

I want to be able, from a Lambda being executed by User A, to trigger an AssumeRole command as User B. In AWS SDK v2, my code looked like this: (simplified)

```
const userBCredentials = secretsProvider.getSecretValue({ userBArn }); // get credentials of User B
const userB_StsClient = new STS({ userBCredentials }); // get an STS Client authenticated as User B
const assumedRoleCredentials = await userB_StsClient.assumeRole({ RoleArn: targetRoleArn }); // get targetRole
const authenticatedSqsClient = new SQS({ assumedRoleCredentials }) // get SQS client authenticated as targetRole in 3rd party AWS account using assumed role credentials
// do SQS operations in 3rd party AWS Account using targetRole
```

We upgraded recently to SDK v3 (about time I know), much of the authentication mechanisms have changed and this code doesn't work anymore.

The new SQS client authentication method requires the use of credential-providers.
I tried the following:

```
import * as aws_cp from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";
import * as aws_sqs from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const userBCredentials = secretsProvider.getSecretValue({ userBArn }); // get credentials of User B
const assumeRoleCP = aws_cp.fromTemporaryCredentials({
  params: { RoleArn: targetRoleArn },
  clientConfig: {
    credentials: { userBCredentials }
  }
});
const sqsClient = new aws_sqs.SQS({ credentials: assumeRoleCP });
```

According to AWS Documentation for aws_cp.fromTemporaryCredentials, the `clientConfig` parameter is supposed to configure the STS client that then uses the assumeRole API. When I then try to use the sqsClient, I get the following error:

`User: userAArn is not authorized to perform: sts:SetSourceIdentity on resource: targetRoleArn`

which lets me know that the credential provider tries to execute assumeRole still using the UserA role. I was hoping that the `clientConfig` parameter would create "under the hood" a STS client authenticated as User B, which would then be allowed to execute assumeRole.